# Single- and Multi-line Edit Controls

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm writing a GUI in GUIDE but when I open it and when I perform an action I keep getting this warning:

```
Warning: Single line Edit Controls can not have multi-line text 
> In openfig at 135
  In gui_mainfcn>local_openfig at 286
  In gui_mainfcn at 234
  In Var_final at 42 
Warning: Single line Edit Controls can not have multi-line text 
Warning: Single line Edit Controls can not have multi-line text
```

Is it a problem? I've read you need to set the `Max` value to 2, but the warnings seem to persist.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for the [properties of uicontrols](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoinq). You can set the `Max` and `Min` properties of an edit box. I know it seems crazy, but if `Max - Min > 1`, the edit box will accept multiline input; if `Max - Min <= 1`, it is single line only. Otherwise, the `Max` and `Min` properties have no effect on edit box controls.